# Find PDF from approximated MGF

Tags: probability, density-function, moment-generating-function

I have an array of values of MGF (it is evaluated at some points).

The plot of it is shown (blue curve): [image: plot of MGF].

Is it possible to find PDF knowing MGF in such form?

I tried to fit MGF with some curve (you can see that blue and red (approximation) curves almost coincide), however, the error when I calculate pdf from the fitted curve is big.

It appears that small error in MGF leads to big error in PDF.

So, fitting doesn't work and I need to find another way.

Comment: By definition, the PDF is the inverse Laplace transform of the MGF, so you can just perform Laplace inversion on your plotted function.

Comment: The function doesn't have a closed form. It is in the tabulated form.

Comment: there are numerical methods to perform laplace inversion (i'm not familiar with them, but there are many references on Google)

Comment: Can you point me to methods that use tabulated data, not function?

Comment: here is a thread that could get you started : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/numerically-obtaining-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-data

Comment: I've read the post and managed to find a good fit. But the domain of my pdf is only non-negative values. And directly applying Inverse Laplace Transform function gives me an  incorrect result.

Comment: Can you tell us how you got the tabled mgf? Can you get a formula?

Comment: I've calculated it empirically and got an approximation formula.